# How to encode URL parameters in Qt?

Tags: qt, parameters, urlencode

I have the following URL

```
QString url = "http://www.gigacooldomainname.com/"
            + setName + "/"
            + fileName + ".jpg";
```

where setName and fileName are QString variables.

I wish to have the following:

```
QString url = "http://www.gigacooldomainname.com/"
            + QUrlParameter::encode(setName) + "/"
            + QUrlParameter::encode(fileName) + ".jpg";
```

Unfortunately there is not such QUrlParameter class or encode method.

I know I can write one by myself but was curious if there is already an existing solution in Qt.

I am also not interested in Q3Url::encode solution since I don't have the Q3Url headers.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [QUrl::toPercentEncoding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qurl.html#toPercentEncoding) (static method ;))

Comment: and how do you do this in QML ?

Comment: @Nulik, `encodeURIComponent()`. Posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 4):

In QML you can use `encodeURIComponent(str)`, it's a [standard JS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) that is [supported by QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-functionlist.html).